# Incorrect date returning when casting from varchar to date

Tags: sql, vertica, to-date

When casting from a varchar data type to a date datatype, my query results are altering the day of the original field. For example, the below two queries

```
     select to_Date('2017-12-15 00:11:10.167664+00', 'YYYY-MM-DD')

     select '2017-12-15 00:11:10.167664+00'::date
```

return a value of "2017-12-14".  I am querying a vertica database using DataGrip.

Comment: what timezone is your postgresql instance in?

Comment: Both of these expressions return the date `2017-12-15` in Postgres, regardless of your current timezone setting.

Comment: The timezone of the database is UTC, however i'm casting from a varchar, so I would assume timezone doesn't play a factor since the original field is not in a timestamp.

Comment: When I run "select getdate()::date;" the expected value of "2018-04-03" is returned.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with postgresql, if you're asking about a vertica database? If you cast that string to a date+time, what is the result? That might shed light on the timezone hypothesis.

Comment: May be you can try `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` to verify that your expectation of the timezone value matches reality.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the leftmost 10 characters of the string and then convert to date, e.g.:

`SELECT TO_DATE(LEFT('2017-12-15 00:11:10.167664+00',10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`